# Remove unchecked value from array

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When the value (item-1) is checked it displays into the console, however when it is unchecked the value (item-1) remains inside of the array. I'm trying to remove item-1 when it is unchecked from the array.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const value = 'Insert into array';
let specArr = [];

item.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  
//   Push value into array
    if (item.checked) {
        specArr.push(`${value}`)
        console.log(specArr);

//    Remove value from array
    } else if (!item.checked) {
        let index = specArr.indexOf(specArr)
        if (index != -1) {
            specArr.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(specArr);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<input class="item" type="checkbox" > Item 1
```

Comment: `let index = specArr.indexOf( value )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look for `indexOf` `value` in `specArr` not the `valueOf` `specArr` in `specArr`

```
let index = specArr.indexOf(value)
```

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const value = 'Insert into array';
let specArr = [];

item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

  //   Push value into array
  if (item.checked) {
    specArr.push(`${value}`)
    console.log(specArr);

    //    Remove value from array
  } else if (!item.checked) {
    let index = specArr.indexOf(value)
    if (index != -1) {
      specArr.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(specArr);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="item" type="checkbox"> Item 1
```

Comment: Thank you @decpk, the solution worked great.

Answer (score 0):

`specArr.indexOf(specArr)` is looking for the first occurence of `specArr` in `specArr`, which does not exist. Instead, look for `value`.

Try:

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const value = 'Insert into array';
let specArr = [];

item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (item.checked) {
    specArr.push(`${value}`)
    console.log(specArr);
  } else if (!item.checked) {
    let index = specArr.indexOf(value)
    if (index != -1) {
      specArr.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(specArr);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="item" type="checkbox"> Item 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.filter() function is good fit for this problem. makes the code simple and smart.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');
const value = 'Insert into array';
let specArr = [];

item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (item.checked) {
    specArr.push(`${value}`)
  } else {
    specArr = specArr.filter(item => item !== value)
  }
  console.log(specArr);
})
```

```html
<input class="item" type="checkbox"> Item 1
```